# How to detect whether Chrome is installed on Linux via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, linux, google-chrome, window, navigator

I have a bug in my app, that appears only on the Chrome installed on Linux. Everything works fine in all other browsers and on android, but on Linux Chrome I have a bug. How to get around this? I can detect chrome via `window.chrome` but if I check `window.navigator.platform.slice(0, 5) == 'Linux'` it will returns `true` also on Android, and I do not want it. What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add an extra check to see if the user is on android with the following code:

```
var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1; 
var isLinux = navigator.platform.slice(0, 5) == 'Linux';
              
if(!isAndroid) { 
  console.log("Device is NOT Android Phone"); 
  if(isLinux) {
    /* This code will run on Linux but not on Android devices */
  }
}
```